# How does JavaFX determine EventTarget paths?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently trying to convert TUIO touch events to JavaFX events. This works for the most part, but when using those programmatically created events, the path that the event takes seems to differ from the path that is taken when enabling Windows 7 native touch and disabling TUIO input.

More specifically, touch events from Windows 7 touch are correctly sent to a Rectangle that is shown on the Scene, but custom touch events are sent to the Scene instead.

Can anyone explain/advise on how JavaFX knows where to send TouchEvents when they are fired using TouchEvent.fireEvent(..)?

Link to method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#fireEvent-javafx.event.EventTarget-javafx.event.Event-

Comment: What is the `EventTarget` argument you pass to the `fireEvent` method?

Comment: I pass it the `Scene` which contains my `Rectangle`. When using Windows 7 native touch, the target of events is also that `Scene`. 
I've taken a more closer look at how JavaFX propagates its events through the dispatcher chain; the event should be sent to the same nodes in the hierarchy, but apparently I am missing some crucial piece of information.

Comment: You have to pass in the rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Event.fireEvent(target, event)`, `target` is the final (inner-most) target. If you pass the Scene as the target, then the event will not descend any deeper than the Scene. You need to fire the event on the Rectangle, if you want to be able to handle it there. You can use JFXtras' [NodeUtil.getNode](http://jfxtras.org/doc/8.0/jfxtras-common/jfxtras/util/NodeUtil.html#getNode-javafx.scene.Parent-double-double-java.lang.Class-) method to find the node at the given position relative to the scene:

```
Node target = NodeUtil.getNode(scene.getRoot(), sceneX, sceneY, Node.class);
Event.fireEvent(target, event);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. 
I assume that the nodeClass argument works as a filter to get a specific type of `Node`?

Comment: Yes. If you pass in `Rectangle.class`, but the node at that position is a `Label`, it will be a no hit.